# How to init tableWidget?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I've just started with Qt. I saw some articles, but don't understand one thing.

[Here it is.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779274/how-can-use-qtablewidget)

At this link `filesTable` comes from nowhere. I don't understand where it was inited?

Another example.

```
   void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount('');


    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount('');


}
```

What is

> tableWidget

? I mean, how I can create it?

Sorry for such question. I have to.

Comment: `tableWidget` is a `QTableWidget` which provides an item-based table view for your application. You can see the Qt documentation about it: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QTableWidget.html#details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filesTable` could be a [member variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_classes#Basic_declaration_and_member_variables) declared in the header file. If you're new to `C++`, you should probably start by learning `C++` first, and then start using `Qt`.

`tableWidget` is a variable that points to a `QTableWidget` type object, which was created in the [Qt Designer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html). It was declared somewhere in the ui header file, for example `ui_mainwindow.h`. This is a file that is usually auto generated by Qt Creator.